# rails namespacing models - associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to use a has_many :through  association, it seems to look for the generic key in the join table.  Example

```
class Ots::Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars, :class_name => '::Ots::FooBar', :foreign_key => :ots_foo_id
  has_many :bars, :class_name => '::Ots::Bar', :through => :foo_bars
end

class Ots::Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars, :class_name => '::Ots::FooBar', :foreign_key => :ots_bar_id
  has_many :bars, :class_name => '::Ots::Bar', :through => :foo_bars
end

class Ots::FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, :class_name => "::Ots::Foo", :foreign_key => :ots_foo_id
  belongs_to :bar, :class_name => "::Ots::Bar", :foreign_key => :ots_bar_id
end

f = Foo.find(1)
f.bars  =># invalid column name 'bar_id'
```

Is this what I should expect?  Is there a more elegant solution to namespacing?